# XML as DataSource

Tags: asp.net, xml, gridview, binding

I have an XML file called employee. I want to bind the XML file to a GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably is looking for [asp:XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource.aspx):

```
<asp:XmlDataSource runat="server" ID="XmlDataSource1" DataFile="~/App_Data/data.xml" XPath="//item" />
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can via DataSet then bind dataSet object to datagrid.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84sxtbxh(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Thanx a lot... Is it possible without using dataset?

Comment: @aparnakarthik No. I don't think so